# No response from database query as JSON

Tags: php, http, ionic-framework

I want to get an array of articles that are liked by the current user that's logged in but I don't get any response from my server. I am doing a http post with userId set that will be used in my query that I'm using to get liked articles by that specific user. My query is as following:

> SELECT *, (CASE likes.userId WHEN $userId THEN 1 END) AS liked FROM article INNER JOIN likes on likes.articleId = article.id WHERE likes.userId = '$userId'

I do get the userId from the http post in my PHP file but somehow I get the feeling that the query isn't getting runned by my PHP file.

The code of my PHP file is as following:

```
require "dbconnect.php";

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

if(isset($data))
{
$request = json_decode($data);

$userId = $request->userId;
}

$sql = "SELECT *, (CASE likes.userId WHEN '$userId' THEN 1 END) AS liked         FROM article INNER JOIN likes on likes.articleId = article.id WHERE likes.userId    = '$userId'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$likedata[] = $row;
}

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count > 0)
{
echo json_encode($likedata);
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: echo the query $sql and then exit; and check whether you are getting specific query value

Comment: @Chrisshi I ran the query multiple times in the database itself aswell with my own userId and it shows my liked articles and this is the output I get [picture](https://imgur.com/a/rppLkck)

Comment: print the likedata[] array and check whether the query is returning any value

Comment: @Chrisshi I printed the array and all it returns is this https://imgur.com/a/EfAWPdX

Comment: Can you remove the if($count > 0) { } condition and just echo json_encode($likedata);

Comment: @Chrisshi I did many times when I do it it returns nothing and no response data available. But when I do it like : json_encode("Your array is: $likedata") it will output : Your array is: Array

Comment: Try like this 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$likedata[] = json_encode($row);
}

Comment: @Chrisshi I tried what you said and it returns "Array" and on my server I get the following error code: "Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion"

Comment: Leave that and try this json_encode($likedata,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);  It may due to non-utf8 encoded characters

Comment: @Chrisshi it finally returns value's because of the answer you told me ! thank you so much Chris!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this json_encode($likedata,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); It may due to non-utf8 encoded characters